# Pass two variables in a javascript created onchange

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using DataTables and have a checkbox. On change I trigger a function. I want to pass two variables to the function like so:

```
{data: null,
      className: "center",
      render: function(data,type,row) {
            alert(data.sesId);
           if(data.checkedIn === "N"){
               return ("<input type='checkbox' id=" + data.patId + " name='update' onchange='patientCheckInFunction(this," + data.sesId + ")' style='zoom: 2.0;'>");
           }else{
               return ("<input type='checkbox' id=" + data.patId + " name='update' onchange='patientCheckInFunction(this," + data.sesId + ")' style='zoom: 2.0;' checked>");
           }
        },
},
```

This gives me an "Unexpected token ')'" in the console log.

There is no error if I have:

```
return ("<input type='checkbox' id=" + data.patId + " name='update' onchange='patientCheckInFunction(this)' style='zoom: 2.0;'>");
```

However, I do want to pass both variables.

Comment: If `data.sesId` is not numeric you need additional quotes to be rendered in the html to encapsulate that string

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
return ("<input type='checkbox' id='"+ data.patId +"' name='update' onchange='patientCheckInFunction(\"" + this + "\",\"" + data.sesId +"\")' style='zoom: 2.0;'>");
```

Comment: `+this+` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I was not using "name" so I ended up doing this:

```
return ("<input type='checkbox' id=" + data.patId + " name=" + data.sesId + " onchange='patientCheckInFunction(this, this.name)' style='zoom: 2.0;'>");
```